# Using an `if` statement inside a Pandas DataFrame's `assign` method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, lambda

### Intro and reproducible code snippet

I'm having a hard time performing an operation on a few columns that requires the checking of a condition using an `if/else` statement.

More specifically, I'm trying to perform this check within the confines of the [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method of a Pandas Dataframe. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do

```py
# Importing Pandas
import pandas as pd

# Creating synthetic data
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                      'col2':[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,1010]})

# Creating a separate output DataFrame that doesn't overwrite 
# the original input DataFrame
out_df = my_df.assign(
    # Successfully creating a new column called `col3` using a lambda function
    col3=lambda row: row['col1'] + row['col2'],

    # Using a new lambda function to perform an operation on the newly 
    # generated column. 
    bleep_bloop=lambda row: 'bleep' if (row['col3']%8 == 0) else 'bloop')
```

The code above yeilds a `ValueError`:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`

When trying to investigate the error, I found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941472/python-3-lambda-error-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous). It seems that `lambda` functions don't always work very nicely with conditional logic in a DataFrame, mostly due to the DataFrame's attempt to deal with things as Series.

### A few dirty workarounds

#### Use `apply`

A dirty workaround would be to make `col3` using the `assign` method as indicated above, but then create the `bleep_bloop` column using an `apply` method instead:

```py
out_sr = (my_df.assign(
    col3=lambda row: row['col1'] + row['col2'])
    .apply(lambda row: 'bleep' if (row['col3']%8 == 0) 
                               else 'bloop', axis=1))
```

The problem here is that the code above returns only a Series with the results of the `bleep_bloop` column instead of a new DataFrame with both `col3` and `bleep_bloop`.

#### On the fly vs. multiple commands

Yet another approach would be to break one command into two:

```py
out_df_2 = (my_df.assign(col3=lambda row: row['col1'] + row['col2']))
out_df_2['bleep_bloop'] = out_df_2.apply(lambda row: 'bleep' if (row['col3']%8 == 0) 
                               else 'bloop', axis=1)
```

This also works, but I'd really like to stick to the on-the-fly approach where I do everything in one chained command, if possible.

### Back to the main question

Given that the workarounds I showed above are messy and don't really get the job done like I need, is there any other way I can create a new column that's based on using a conditional `if/else` statement?

The example I gave here is pretty simple, but consider that the real world application would likely involve applying custom-made functions (e.g.: `out_df=my_df.assign(new_col=lambda row: my_func(row))`, where `my_func` is some complex function that uses several other columns from the same row as inputs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is that you considered the lambda to act on rows, while it acts on full columns in a vectorized way. You need to use vectorized functions:

```
import numpy as np

out_df = my_df.assign(
    col3=lambda d: d['col1'] + d['col2'],
    bleep_bloop=lambda d: np.where(d['col3']%8, 'bloop', 'bleep')
)

print(out_df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3 bleep_bloop
0     1    11    12       bloop
1     2    22    24       bleep
2     3    33    36       bloop
3     4    44    48       bleep
4     5    55    60       bloop
5     6    66    72       bleep
6     7    77    84       bloop
7     8    88    96       bleep
8     9    99   108       bloop
9    10  1010  1020       bloop
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the prompt reply! I know I didn't make this explicit in the main question, but what if I actually want to do complex set of branching `if-else`s? I think np.where only handles condition. In that case, is it possible to use [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)?

Comment: @FelipeD. Yes of course, as long as the used method returns a 1D object (or 2D with a single column). This would be `assign(new=np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], [out1, out2, out3], default))`

Answer (score 1):

Or for more than 2 conditions you can use np.select:

```py
import numpy as np  
out_df=(my_df.assign(
    col3 = lambda df_ : df_['col1'] + df_['col2'],
    bleep_bloop=lambda df_: np.select(condlist=[df_['col3']%8==0,
                                                df_['col3']%8==1,
                                                df_['col3']>100 ],
                                      choicelist=['bleep',
                                                  'bloop',
                                                  'bliip'],
                                      default='bluup')))
```

The good thing about np.select is that it works like where(vectorized functions therefore faster) and you can put as many condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be needing a complex logic in your final column, as you mentioned it makes sense to create a separate function for it and apply it to the rows.

```py
def my_func(x):
    if (x['col1'] + x['col2']) % 8 == 0:
        return 'bleep'
    else:
        return 'bloop'

my_df['bleep_bloop'] = my_df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x), axis=1)
```

When you pass the x to the function, you are in fact passing each row and can use any of the column values inside your function like x['col1'] and so on. This way you can create as complex a function as you need. Note that axis=1 is required here to pass the rows.

I did not include creation of col3 just to provide a sample.